# Can't view old Hotmail emails after Outlook setup

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp, pop3, hotmail

Ok I actually have an msn account "myname@msn.com" Ever since I tried to view my emails using Outlook 2007, I no longer can view my old emails from the Hotmail web interface.

I think I messed up the Outlook configuration because I could view new emails from Outlook but I could not send any emails from Outlook, getting something like "Cannot connect to SMTP blah blah blah".

I want to get rid of Outlook, undo what I did before. So I tried deleting on my machine my email account by going to Control Panel --> Mail --> and deleting my email account. But no luck.

Anyone knows how I can see my old emails from Hotmail account? I don't know why Outlook would interfere with the Hotmail Web interface. Isn't Outlook and Hotmail different clients. I can view my old emails from Outlook but not from Hotmail web interface. I mean when I setup Outlook did all my emails get moved to another email server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have configured Outlook to download all messages (POP) and delete from server.

Either way, this belongs on superuser.com, voting to migrate it there.

Comment: yeah I realize that now. thanks.  I guess not good idea to have that setting ON by default.